# Filter rows by count of two column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

```
Card(
  MembershipNumber,
  EmbossLine,
  status,
  EmbossName
)
```

with sample data

```
(0009,0321,'E0','Finn')
(0009,0322,'E1','Finn')
(0004,0356,'E0','Mary')
(0004,0398,'E0','Mary')
(0004,0382,'E1','Mary')
```

I want to retrieve rows such that only those rows should appear that have `count` of `MembershipNumber > 1` AND count of `status='E0' > 1`.

**For Example** The query should return following result

```
(0004,0356,'E0','Mary')
(0004,0398,'E0','Mary')
```

I have the query for filtering it with `MembershipNumber` count but cant figure out how to filter by status='E0'. Here's the query so far

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(MembershipNumber)OVER(partition BY EmbossName) AS cnt
        FROM   card) A
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Comment: Add `WHERE status = 'E0'` in your subquery.

Comment: I did but then its returning all those that have status= 'E0'. In case of my example it will also return `(0009,0321,'E0','Finn')`. Which is not required

Comment: Are you sure, because it works fine on my machine: `SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Count(MembershipNumber)OVER(partition BY EmbossName) AS cnt
        FROM   card
  WHERE status = 'E0'
  ) A
WHERE  cnt > 1 `

Comment: Using @RagingBull's fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c34a4b/10/0

Comment: Its working! My bad I was placing the where clause in the last.

Comment: @FelixPamittan If you can add your answer on this post I will mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `WHERE status = 'E0'` inside your subquery:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c34a4b/10/0) (*credit to Raging Bull for the fiddle*)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(MembershipNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY EmbossName) AS cnt
    FROM card
    WHERE status = 'E0'
)A
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
select t1.*
from card t1 left join
    (select EmbossName
     from card
     where [status]='E0'
     group by EmbossName,[status]
having count(MembershipNumber)>1 ) t2 on t1.EmbossName=t2.EmbossName
where t2.EmbossName is not null and [status]='E0'
```

Result:

```
MembershipNumber    EmbossLine  status  EmbossName
---------------------------------------------------
4                   356         E0      Mary
4                   398         E0      Mary
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c34a4b/8)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
WITH cnt AS (
    SELECT MembershipNumber, status
        FROM Card
        WHERE status = 'E0'
        GROUP BY MembershipNumber, status
        HAVING COUNT(MembershipNumber) > 1 AND COUNT(status) > 1
)
SELECT c.*
    FROM Card c
    INNER JOIN cnt
        ON c.MembershipNumber = cnt.MembershipNumber
           AND c.status = cnt.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
   [MembershipNumber] SMALLINT
  ,[EmbossLine] SMALLINT
  ,[status] CHAR(2)
  ,[EmbossName] VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([MembershipNumber], [EmbossLine], [status], [EmbossName])
VALUES (0009,0321,'E0','Finn')
      ,(0009,0322,'E1','Finn')
      ,(0004,0356,'E0','Mary')
      ,(0004,0398,'E0','Mary')
      ,(0004,0382,'E1','Mary');

SELECT [MembershipNumber]
      ,[EmbossLine]
      ,[status]
      ,[EmbossName]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT([MembershipNumber]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmbossName]) AS cnt1
          ,SUM(IIF([status] = 'E0' , 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmbossName]) AS cnt2
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
WHERE  cnt1 > 1 
    AND cnt2 > 1
    AND [status] = 'E0';
```

[image]

The idea is to add a second `counter`, but instead of `COUNT` function to use `SUM` function for counting only the rows that have `[status] = 'E0'`. Then, in the where clause we are filtering by the two counters and `[status] = 'E0'`.